# fontAwesome icons do not work inside my flutter app

Tags: flutter, font-awesome

I'm currently working on a side project and when I have included a font-awesome icon inside my app, it does not show up and instead, a blank box with two lines intersecting with each other like the letter x, how to fix this?

```
class ImageHoldingComponent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
   _ImageHoldingComponentState createState() => 
 _ImageHoldingComponentState();
```

}

```
class _ImageHoldingComponentState extends State<ImageHoldingComponent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
   child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.python)
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The author of `font_awesome_flutter` package suggests the [following](https://github.com/brianegan/font_awesome_flutter/issues/28#issuecomment-460109786) steps for anyone who has icons not showing problem:

1. Stopping the app
2. Running flutter clean in your app directory
3. Deleting the app from your simulator / emulator / device
4. Rebuild & Deploy the app.

Also make sure to set `uses-material-design` to `true` in pubspec.yaml file.

Answer (score 6):

This happens when you start using the older version of font_awesome_flutter and because the virtual device cache is stored when you build the Flutter app, so every time you change the icon you have to stop the emulator and rebuild it.

My experience is:

1. Stop `main.dart` (Android Emulator)
2. In `pubspec.yaml` add (font_awesome_flutter) new version

> font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1 //new verison
```

And Then click

"Pub get"

at the top of Flutter commands

3. Run the emulator again (start main.dart)

Answer (score 3):

If your app is running on the emulator or device just
**stop it and relaunch it again**
it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just save the from pupspec.yaml file under dependices and say pub get, don't forget to import it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add font_awesome_flutter: ^10.3.0 package in pubspec.yaml file.
Then use like this

```
    FaIcon(
           Icons.access_alarm,
           color: whatsappColor,
           size: 30,
          ),
```